# XPages Extending UIJdbcConnectionManager

Tags: xpages

In v8.5.3 you had to be sure and place a check next to the 'com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library' in order to use either of these lines of code:

```
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.jdbc.UIJdbcConnectionManager;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc.datasource.xpages.JdbcPoolDataSource;
```

However, after installing the latest version of the extension library which now has the relational controls as part of the core extension library you should only need to place a check mark next to the 'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library' to import these same lines of code.

Problem is that an error stating component cannot be resolved is occurring.  This error occurs whether using the minimum supported release value of 9.0.1 or minimum release required by the XPage features used, [image], or placing a check mark next to the 'com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library' and/or the 'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library', [image].

Comment: Just to clarify, where is the error occurring - at build time or at run time? And is the latest ExtLib installed in both Designer and server?

Comment: Error is occurring at build time and ExtLib is installed in both Designer and Server.

Comment: just found out that the most current version is not yet installed on the server as we had thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those classes now resolve at:

```
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.component.jdbc.UIJdbcConnectionManager
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.datasource.xpages.JdbcPoolDataSource
```

Note the added `relational` package

I'd do a search of your entire application for any references to `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc` & `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.jdbc` and replace with `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc` & `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.component.jdbc` respectively. Search all files, ".xsp", ".java", ".xsp-config", ".xml" etc.

Comment: Changed those imports to the below and still not working even with the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library checked:

`import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.component.jdbc.UIJdbcConnectionManager;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.datasource.xpages.JdbcPoolDataSource;`

Comment: Hmm strange. With the extlib.library & relational.library both checked, those imports should work. What version of the extlib are you using , presumably 901_v10 or 901_v11? Only other idea: did you use the updateSite-designer.zip to install the extlib to designer, not the updateSite.zip which is for the server?

Comment: plug-in details for the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational shows version 9.0.1v00_10_20141105-0922.  I used the updateSite-designer.zip for my client.  Still not sure if  the server has this version installed or not and presume they would be using the updateSite.zip.

Does it matter if the server has it installed when I get the error during build time?

Comment: No, if you are getting the error at build time in the Designer console, the server is not yet involved. Do the Designer error logs show anything unusual (Help -> Support -> View Trace)?

Comment: this is what the tracelog is showing for the Source Class method 'com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ParseUtil.getClassForName:

**CLFAD0095E: Format error reading the class org.nfcu.xsp.component.NfcuConnectionManager
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE113 unexpected EOF; class=org/nfcu/xsp/component/NfcuConnectionManager, offset=0
CLFAD0090W: The component-class (org.nfcu.xsp.component.NfcuConnectionManager) could not be resolved for the component with component-type com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc.JdbcConnectionManager.**

Comment: That suggests that the component-class you have set for your control is incorrect. It should be "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.JdbcConnectionManager". I'd do a search of your entire application for any references to "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc" and replace with "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc". Search all files, ".xsp", ".java", ".xsp-config", ".xml" etc.

Comment: looks like changing the component-class in the WEB-INF\lib folder did the trick, but I also had to select the 'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library' in the Xsp Properties.  That is interesting because I thought, like many others I am guessing, that the JDBC support files were part of the core Extension Library with the latest release.  Can you explain why this library is required to be selected?

Comment: Relational is part of the main extlib now as it is installed by default (no long requiring ExtlibX to be installed too). However, it is not enabled by default, it requires adding the relational library in the xsp properties as you point out. When we decided to move the feautre, we also decided to still keep the feature somewhat separated, hence the 2nd library. This is because many xpages apps will make no use of the relational feature

Comment: Sorry, but the last change allowed me to build without errors.  Now when I try to launch it tells me: **The component-class (org.nfcu.xsp.component.NfcuConnectionManager) could not be resolved for the component with component-type com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc.JdbcConnectionManager**.  I did a search for the component-type string and found nothing.  Does that mean something isn't installed on server?

Comment: I don't recognise the org.ncfu class. Is that not your own component class?

Comment: Yes, it was created by a colleague to extend the standard connectionManager because we cannot use hard-coded username/password.  SO is going to stop our conversation soon so if we can continue on BleedYellow or directly via email, dwain_wuerfel@navyfederal.org, that would be great